# Highcharts not displaying data on live site

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm writing a stacked bar chart that is working fine on my local machine, however when it is running on a live server it doesn't plot any of the data points. I've considered that it could be the api is taking longer on the live site to get the data, or maybe highcharts is not loading fast enough, but the x-axis populates the values correctly and the library is loading locally (also happens with CDN).

I can even log the values of the chart series and see everything fine. It just doesn't display any data with a line designating 0 on the Y axis. Anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

```
$.getJSON( 'URL TO API', function(data){
// Sample data output
//   data = [
//    { 'name' : 'Items', data : [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3'] }
//    { 'name' : 'losses', data : [2, 3, 1] }
//    { 'name' : 'Wins', data : [5, 2, 0] }
//  ]
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                renderTo: 'chart',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Wins and Losses'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: data[0]['data']
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name : data[1]['name'],
                    data : data[1]['data']
                },
                {
                    name : data[2]['name'],
                    data : data[2]['data']
                },
            ]
        });


    });
```

Comment: Have you looked in your browsers error console for any messages? Also, look at the source code from within the browser to see if the data is populated.

Comment: There are no errors. And I can see that the data variable from the ajax response is populated. I can also check chart.series and see that it has data populated as well immediately after rendering.

Comment: Could you attach some data-sample? Maybe you simple have all data points equal to 0?

Comment: There is a sample set of data in the comments of the snippet. Data is being returned from the api, and as I said, chart.series has complete objects with all of the data, and coordinate plots included.

Comment: I would expect something is wrong with the API, simple test case without API and hardcoded data: http://jsfiddle.net/9FkJc/61/ Do you have any errors in the JS console? Or maybe yournumbers are strings or something similar?